# My drop down menu is above my content. need guidance

Tags: html, css

My Drop down menu is under my content. Can anybody help me get it to go over?
Code -

```css
body {


  padding: 0;


  margin: 0;


  font-family: Arial;


  font-size: 17px;


  background-color: #333;


}


#nav {


  background-color: #222;


  border-bottom: 5px solid #d30c43;


}


#nav_wrapper {


  width: 1000px;


  margin: 0 auto;


  text-align: left;


}


#nav ul {


  list-style-type: none;


  padding: 0;


  margin: 0;


  position: relative;


  min-width: 200px;


  margin-bottom: -3px;


}


#nav ul li {


  display: inline-block;


}


#nav ul li a,


visited {


  display: block;


  padding: 15px;


  text-decoration: none;


}


#nav ul li:hover ul {


  display: block;


}


#nav ul ul {


  display: none;


  position: absolute;


  background-color: #333;


  border: 5px solid #222;


  border-top: 0;


  margin-left: -5px;


}


#nav ul ul li {


  display: block;


}


#nav_wrapper ul ul li:hover a {} #content {


  margin-left: auto;


  margin-right: auto;


  overflow: visible;


  width: 75%;


  position: relative;


}


#nav ul li ul li a {


  color: #FFF;


}


#nav ul ul li a:hover {


  color: #d30c43;


}


.primary a:link {


  color: #FFF;


}


.primary a:visited {


  color: #fff;


}


.primary a:hover {


  color: #d30c43;


}


* {


  margin: 0px;


}


#slider {


  height: 400px;


  width: 650px;


  margin: 50px auto;


  position: relative;


  border-radius: 4px;


  overflow: hidden;


  float: left;


  border: 3px solid black;


}


#image {


  height: 400px;


  width: 650px;


  position: absolute;


}


.left_hold {


  height: 400px;


  width: 100px;


  position: absolute;


  top: 0px;


  left: 0px;


}


.right_hold {


  height: 400px;


  width: 100px;


  position: absolute;


  top: 0px;


  right: 0px;


}


.left {


  height: 50px;


  width: 50px;


  position: absolute;


  top: 40%;


  left: 20px;


  opacity: 0;


  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;


  cursor: pointer;


}


.right {


  height: 50px;


  width: 50px;


  position: absolute;


  top: 40%;


  right: 20px;


  opacity: 0;


  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;


  cursor: pointer;


}


.left_hold:hover .left {


  opacity: 0.6;


}


.right_hold:hover .right {


  opacity: 0.6;


}


#top10 {


  position: relative;


  margin: 50px auto;


  width: 267px;


  float: right;


  color: #fff;


  height: 286px;


}


.top10click a {


  color: #fff;


}


#topArticle {


  position: relative;


  float: left;


  color: #fff;


  width: 800px;


}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    GameTopic
  </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="js/alert_tut.js"></script>

</head>




<body onLoad="photoA()">


  <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <img style="float:right; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;" src="logo.png" width="200" height="40">
        <div id="strip"></div>
        <ul>
          <li class="primary"><a href="index.html"><b>HOME</b></a>
            <li class="primary"><a href="news.html">News</a>
            </li>

          </li>
          <li class="primary"> <a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="rev-gaming.html">Gaming</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="rev-soft.html">Software</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="rev-hard.html">Hardware</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="rev-custom.html">Custom Builds</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="rev-yt.html">Youtube Channels</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="primary"> <a href="hardware.html">Hardware</a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="rev-hard.html">Reviews</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="hard-parts.html">Best parts</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="hard-budget.html">Budget Builds</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="primary"> <a href="software.html">Software</a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="soft-news.html">News</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="rev-soft.html">Reviews</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="soft-recom.html">Recommended</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="primary"> <a href="gaming.html">Gaming</a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="game-news.html">News</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="game-parts.html">Best Parts</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="game-accesor.html">Best Accessories</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="game-recom.html">Recommended Games</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Nav wrapper end -->
    </div>

    <div id="top10">

      <h5 class="Game10"> GameTopic's Top 10 of the week </h5>
      <div id="t10Title">
        <h4 class="t10list"> Top 10: Indie Games of the Week</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="10Content">
        <ol "listContent">
          <br>

          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>


        </ol>
        <br>
        <div class="top10click">
          <p> <b><u><a href="#">Click here</a></u> to see the full article! </div><b>

                </div>




            </div>
            <div id="topArticle">
               <div id="ArticleTitle"><h1> Article Title</div>
               <div if="ArticleText"> <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                




            </div></div>

            


    <div id="slider">


    <img src="img1.jpg" id="image" >
    <div class="left_hold"><img onClick="photo(-1)" class="left" src="arrow_left.png"></div>
    <div class="right_hold"><img onClick="photo(1)" class="right" src="arrow_right.png"></div>

</div>





</body>
</html>
```

In jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/themastrey99/r8fq6kv8/

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index` in your CSS. A higher numbers puts it in front of other elements and a low number behind (negative numbers are allowed).

Example:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
z-index:10;
```

Comment: thanks. i fixed it before you posted this. i tried the  z-index but i fixed it with position absolute xD

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out for yourself. Best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your menu a z-index to make it appear on top:

```
#nav_wrapper ul {
     z-index: 100;
 }
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp